# Polymer resolvePath for relative resource path

Tags: polymer

I try to solve resource loading error in my vulcanized **Polymer-App**. I’ve already read the docs about the method `resolvePath` but this doesn’t seems to fix the problem. This is my project structure:

```
test
├── assets
│   └── avatar.png
├── components
│   └── custom-elem-with-relative-path-to-avatar.html
└── index.html
```

*custom-elem-with-relative-path-to-avatar.html*

```
<polymer-element name="aw-account” layout vertical>
…
    <img src="{{avatarImage}}" id="profileAvatar" alt="Image for Profile”>
…
</template>
<script>
    Polymer('aw-account', {
        ready: function () {
            this.avatarImage = this.resolvePath('../assets/avatar.png');
            …
</script>
</polymer-element>
```

Due to `../` the image src is one level above the correct folder!

How do I have to use the method `resolvePath` to get the resource **avatar.png** loaded correctly in my **vulcanized-app**?

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
this.resolvePath('./assets/avatar.png')
```

in Polymer 0.5 or

```
this.resolveUrl('./assets/avatar.png')
```

in Polymer 1.0